# JQuery Tabs Stopped Working

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

Website showed tabs when it was originally created in 2010.  No longer showing.  I've tried several fixes, but it persists in not loading the style.

http://www.rlulaw.com/members.php

Comment: If you open browser console you will see 6 errors that says 403 HTTP error. You load all your scripts from http://jqueryui.com/ site. Try to download them instead and place at your server-side

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a permissions error, here is the JS console dump from Chrome:

```
GET http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.core.js 403 (Forbidden) members.php:14
GET http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js 403 (Forbidden) members.php:14
GET http://jqueryui.com/jquery-1.7.2.js 403 (Forbidden) members.php:14
GET http://jqueryui.com/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css 403 (Forbidden) members.php:11
GET http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js 403 (Forbidden) members.php:14
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined members.php:19
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Google Code for linking your scripts... Use these:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```